# Stringification in swift

Tags: swift

Is there anyway to do stringification in swift? , since there is no preprocessor it seems kind of difficult.

What I'd like to do is something similar to the following code.

```
// log a variable name and its value
#define LOGV(V) NSLog(@"%s = %@", #V, V);
NSString *myString = @"this";
LOGV(myString);    // prints out ->  "myString = ???"
```

After looking at `dump` it seems that there is no way of reflecting a variable name.

```
let myString = "this"
dump(myString, name:"myString", indent: 0 maxDepth: 0, maxItems: 1)
```

Comment: Typically this type of code should not be used. That's why there's no way to do it in Swift (and in most of other high level languages).

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to do the same thing in Swift,
so I recently wrote debug-logging util which stringifies variables at runtime instead (reading entire code!)

You might find this interesting.
https://github.com/inamiy/DebugLog

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this in Swift. If you ABSOLUTELY want to do this, its always possible to run the C preprocessor over your Swift source.